# Searching for hash tag via thinking sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Is it possible to search hash tag via thinking_spinx? Can't find solution.
Need to find all titles with hash tag only: "title#text","#text", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make sure Sphinx is indexing the hash character - which is done via the [charset_table](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.1.html#conf-charset-table) setting. Thinking Sphinx finds this value in `config/sphinx.yml` (create it if you haven't already), which is set up via environments, much like `config/database.yml`.

```
development:
  charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, \#, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F"
```

All other characters and character ranges listed are Sphinx's default set for UTF-8, which is what Thinking Sphinx uses by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pat. I use this table and forgot about it.